# how to configure network to enable discovery service

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to set up a fabric network in multiple machines using aws.
The problem I am having is that I am trying to enable discovery service using node sdk. It works  when I am in localhost using docker, but doesn't work if I have a distributed network in multiple machines because it tries to endorse to localhost instead of the assigned ips.

I don't have the option `asLocalhost` set to true so I don't know why it tries to do it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In the SDK must be set the Discovery options accordingly with your network configuration.

Below you can find the link to the official NodeJS Fabric SDK:

https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/module-fabric-network.Gateway.html#~DiscoveryOptions

Here also a tutorial on Discovery Service:

https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/tutorial-discovery.html

Comment: if i dont enable discovery the endorsing works in my distributed network, it seems like discovery isnt mapping the ip correctly to the peers because like the tutorial says if u use a network config file to load all it assigns the names of the peers as hostname:port and that doesnt map to the assigned urls in the config file.
Discovery optoins are as the tutorial says discover:true and aslocalhost:false in my case.